# Filtering out contents of cells in DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image]

The picture above is an example of my DataFrame. It is a large DataFrame and I have a condition I need to check. The 'CC Exp Date' columns has all of its data in the format of:

```
Data1/Data2
```

That is month by year. I want to get all the instances where `Data 2 == 25`. How do I do this?
Help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.loc[df["CC Exp Date"].str.contains("/25")]
```

Comment: I know this is late, but do you think .split() would work for this, I have already solved the issues I had, I'm just curious, would something like:
`df.loc[df["CC Exp Date"].str.split("/")[0] == "25"]`
It may just be more crash proof(or so i think)